# What colors can I use in this educational slide that is more appealing?

Tags: color, palette

I want to instruct people about how SSL works, (HTTPS) and that involves "color mixing" as demonstrated in [this link](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/105376/396), and this graphic.

Is there any other color combination I can use that would have a more appealing pallet or just so I don't end up with a nasty brown?

[image]

Comment: Well, all the primary colors mixed together do make brown. You could start with what you want your final colors to be and try to reverse engineer them from there... You could also try something with stripes or patterns that includes all the colors, though that might get wild. (Also, Bob's colors are off. Yellow and teal don't make blue, but yellow and blue might make that tealy green.)

Comment: Are there any visual tools I can use to help me make the right colors appear?

Comment: Maybe I'll just replace blue with "glitter" or some other texture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment above, you can do this by hand by picking a non-primary color that you like for the end pieces, and reverse engineer what colors might be used to get that result.

I tried this with a violet color and a teal color, and came up with the following results:

[image]

The key will be to pick something that is not Red, Yellow or Blue for your end color.

If mixing colors in your head doesn't come naturally to you, here's an online mixing tool that might help: http://trycolors.com/. It lets you mix colors to see the results, and also has a pallet of pre-mixed colors that you can expand to see what colors it's made of. This won't help with reverse engineering, but it might be helpful to play with to see if your final result makes sense.

Comment: how did you reverse engineer that?

Comment: @LamonteCristo A few years of color theory and mixing lots of paint by hand. ;) I added a link to an online color mixer to my answer that might help you visualize things better.